# python keeps crashing whenever CNN model is being trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am really looking for your help.

I have GTX-1070 which is 8vram.
I downloaded tensorflow-gpu, cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.0 for cuda 9.0.

and everything works fine with DNN. GPU is also working fine.

but whenever I try to train any model that has to do with image, it crashes.
Currently I am working with keras pre-trained VGG16.

I tried using smaller batch-size, resized image down to 64x64.
When I look at the process, GPU is used 0%, then spikes up to 100% then crashes.
Spyder says "kernel died, restarting".

Is gtx-1070 really that short of memory or am I missing something?

Thanks for reading

Comment: "It crashes" says nothing. You should post the actual error message related to the crash.

Comment: I think it is a Spyder problem rather than the GPU. Try running the python file independently

Comment: Well  i did say  error message was   kernel died. Thats all i get. Dont know whats wrong with it.

Comment: It  crashes the same way in jupyter notebook. Will try python file though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to download Cudnn 7.1.

These are good instructions to follow, and you may consider reinstalling Cuda 9 again. I had to do the same at one point, it was frustrating but haven't had a problem since I got it right.

[Installation Instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar crashing problem before. The cause was my cudnn7.1 and tensorflow-gpu (precompiled with cudnn7.05) versions mismatched. Once taken care, there is no more problem.